# About adjustment to Tobit regression model output

Tags: censoring, tobit-regression

I am using Tobit regression approach to build a prediction model with a dependent variable censored at 0 and 1. Several R packages provide nice functions to train a Tobit model, such as censReg, vglm, AER::tobt, etc.

I also searched up on the Internet on how to calculate predicted values of a Tobit regression model (because I need to implement the model in a quite old school system). It looks like an adjustment is required to applied to the fitted value (see [reference (but it is an SAS example)](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/stat/chap36/sect24.htm)  here), i.e.

$$
E(Y_i)=\Phi(\frac{x_{i}^{'}{\beta}}{\sigma})(x_{i}^{'}{\beta} + \sigma\lambda_i)
$$
, where
$$
\lambda_i = \frac{\phi(x_{i}^{'}{\beta}/\sigma)} {\Phi(x_{i}^{'}{\beta}/\sigma)}
$$
.

From my understanding, the fitted value returned by a Tobit regression function is the term $x_{i}^{'}{\beta}$. So my question is what is this transformation/adjustment for? Is it to get the 'censored' prediction?

Thanks.